# MX Google Maps Search using GPS coordinates sometimes produces wrong result

Tags: mx-google-map

MX Google Maps Version 1.5.3

- Search for these decimal GPS coordinates 52.202191,0.128201 produces
  a good result
- Search for these decimal GPS coordinates 52.217026,0.055114 produces a bad result which is 52.212924, 0.065532 (rounded to 6 places)

These two locations are very close to each other in and around Cambridge, UK.

I have searched for these two GPS coordinates in Google Maps and get the right results. It seems that somehow MX Google Maps is either sending the wrong request to Google Maps, or it is misinterpreting the results.

I was suspicious of the "0.0" part of the latitude so tried searching for 52.217026,0.155114 etc but that still produced invalid results in MX Google Maps, and good results in Google Maps.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you search for the second set of co-ords but put a space after the comma?

Comment: "52.217026, 0.055114" with space after the comma produces the same wrong results.